# I try install dhcp3-server, but /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server file is missing. Whats going on?

Tags: server, dhcp

I've found several how-to's that essentially go through the same process in setting up DHCP.

[Here's](https://serverfault.com/questions/368237/cofiguring-dhcp-server-on-ubuntu) a link that has the list of all steps needed to install and setup DHCP.  I followed all the steps and found that the `sudo /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server restart` portion returns `command not found` only to reveal the the file doesn't even exist.  I've installed (`sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server`) and uninstalled (`sudo apt-get remove dhcp3-server`) two or three times.  I'm pretty sure my config files are good because I've had to check them three times.  But I don't think I'm to that point of being able to see them action it. I can't control the process.

**Why is the file missing?  How is it supposed to get there? Help?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dhcp3-server` package has been transitioned to the new-style "ISC" DHCP package. This package is called `isc-dhcp-server`, and would have been installed when you installed `dhcp3-server`.

The file you're looking for is now `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server`.

Note that you may use the `service` command to start and stop daemons:

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

The `service` tool will handle the different styles of daemon start/stop behaviour (ie, `/etc/init.d/*` vs. `/etc/init/*.conf`).

Comment: Looks like this could be it.  Will mark as correct once I get chance to test.